# Best way to include Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, dll

I have two projects. In one I have included Oracle.DataAccess.dll into project. In csproj it looks like:

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, ...">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>myFolder\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

In another project I am using machine's own Oracle.DataAccess.dll and I haven't included it in project. Csproj file looks like:

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, ...">
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

Which should I use? I have had problem with first one (to include dll to project as a file) but I don't know is this the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Use the NuGet package `Oracle.ManagedDataAcces` made by Oracle. This will include the dll as a file in your project and you will get all the advantages of using a NuGet package.

It will ensure the correct version of the dll is included for everyone and when the application is deployed.

All of the configuration and file manipulation will be done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Include `Oracle.DataAccess` from Nuget package.
Below are the steps to install library:

Go to solution explorer -> right click the project -> manage Nuget packages -> navigate to browse tab ->  type '`Oracle DataAccess`' -> Search -> Scroll down you could see `Oracle.DataAccess` for 64 bit -> install the stable version.

For your information as suggested by previous post, if you install `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` then you may need to change in the existing code.

My suggestion is if you are going to work on new project go with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` since it is a latest one. Suppose if you are going to build existing project then find and install exact version of Oracle.DataAccess.